# How to select from a Postgresql function that requires a table as argument

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a function that requires a table as input, and returns the same table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab1
    (`id` int, `a` int, `b` int, `c` varchar(16), `timestamp` datetime)
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(sp "tab1")
    RETURNS TABLE (
        LIKE "tab1")
    LANGUAGE 'plpython3u'
    AS [...];
```

I want to call it similar to this:

```sql
SELECT * from func()
```

However, this function also requires a table as argument. Because of that, I always called it like this:

```sql
SELECT func (t) FROM "table" AS t WHERE id = 1;
```

but it returned a single column with
`(1,NULL,NULL,SOMERANDOMTEXT,"2021-09-17 20:23:22.788179+00")`

**How can I make the SELECT return separate columns instead of a single `func` column?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:

```
SELECT (func(t.*)).* FROM tab1 AS t WHERE t.id = 1
```

You could use `LATERAL JOIN` too:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tab1,
      LATERAL func(tab1) AS t
WHERE tab1.id = 1;
```